# can we store the value printed by printf() into a unsigned long variable?

Tags: c++, c

I have a following array and a printf() stament,

```
char array[1024] = "My Message: 0x7ffff6be9600";
printf("%.14s", strstr(array, " 0x") + 1);
```

The output of above printf() is 0x7ffff6be9600, 
can we store it into a unsigned long variable?

Comment: I dont know try it and compile your program?

Comment: C or C++? If you want to get a string into a long (printf really has nothing to do with it) you do it differently in the two languages.

Comment: ya, @Kate can u provide it for C++?

Comment: Your question should be tagged correctly - either C or C++. Also, if you're using C++, you should use std::string, not char[] strings. Change your sample a little to show what you're really trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you tagged this as C++, see [istringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istringstream/).

```
using std::istringstream;
const char source_text[] =  "0x7ffff6be9600";
unsigned long value;
istringstream input(source_text);
input >> hex >> value;
```

Answer (score 5):

Look at [sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const char* numBuf = strstr(array, " 0x");
unsigned long number = 0; /* Set default value here. */
if(numBuf)
    number = strtoul(numBuf + 1, 0, 0);
```